# load youtube video dynamically in playerJS using playerJS-youtube

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to play video & youtube using the playerJS and playerJs-youtube plugin.

When I put youtube src in data-setup it works fine just on page load. But i need to populate the youtube video on runtime onClick event.

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3cojnq2/) has my current sample code which dosn't play the youtube video. it actually doesn't load the youtube iframe when i apply the load() function. Please guide me how to achieve this.

Here's the code sample I'm using:

```
<div id="youtube_player" style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS;">
    <video
      id="v2"
      class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
      controls
      autoplay
      width="640" height="264"
      data-setup='{}'
    >
    </video>
</div>
<ul id="playlist">
  <li data-loc="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" data-type="video/mp4">Sintel</li>
  <li data-loc="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/trailer.mp4" data-type="video/mp4">Bunny</li>
  <li data-loc="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" data-type="video/mp4">Oceans</li>
  <li data-loc="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWHpoJT3qK4" data-type="video/youtube">Youtube</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
var list = document.getElementById('playlist');
var items = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];

    item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        var data_type = this.getAttribute("data-type");
        var data_source = this.getAttribute("data-loc");

        if(data_type == 'video/youtube'){
            var p = document.getElementById("v2");
            var v = p.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
            $(v).attr('data-setup', '{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ"}], "youtube": { "iv_load_policy": 1 } }');
            $(v).prop('data-setup', '{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ"}], "youtube": { "iv_load_policy": 1 } }');

            v.load();
            v.play();
        }

    });
}
</script>
```